# how to view the xls document in java swing

Tags: java, excel, swing, frame, xls

I am creating a window application using java swing.
Now I want to show the Excel(xls) document inside the swing component(Frame/Panel) like this.

How can I get this. Any one have idea about this???

Comment: Like (frame/panel) swing controls.

Comment: @StanislavL: Ya I accepted the answer for the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) will help reading your excel file. It helps extracting the values from the sheets (and can do much more, of course). But of course, you'll still have to design the UI.

---

Here something that may help (pretty old stuff but maybe still valuable):

[Forum entry mentioning JavaSheet, Jeks and PoiBrowser](http://marc.info/?l=poi-user&m=103748991925208&w=2)

Comment: Ya, of course I am using POI to create and read the excel document.

Comment: But what I want is, is there any built in control or some functions to show/view the excel document inside the window?

Answer (score 0):

I have used jxl (http://jxl.sourceforge.net/) to parse and read excel files in Java. Displaying it in Swing can then be a map dump of excel cells.